# Facebook Like button plugin not showing up in my browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, dreamweaver

Im using dreamweaver cs5. I'm trying to put a facebook like box with the faces on a website for the first time.

When I preview my website in a browser (not server), the plugin doesn't show so Im guessing there is something wrong with my code.

Any advice is much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
<div class="float-left">
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/UnifiedSweden?ref=ts&amp;fref=ts"    data-send="true" data-width="300" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>
```

Comment: Without running from a server, so that the document gets not requested via `http(s)://…`, the browser does not know how to resolve the protocol-relative URL given for the JS SDK (`//connect.facebook.net/…`). Make it `http:/connect.facebook.net/…` if you want to test locally without using a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
js.src = "http:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```